# Django forms - show hidden field dependant on another field

Tags: python, django, dependencies

I have a booking form with cost_pp and number_ppl, but I want the number_ppl field to be shown only if there is something entered in the cost_pp.

Is it possible to do this without having to refresh the page and have it happen instantly?

in my forms.py i have:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = 'booking'
        self.title = _('Booking')
        self.action = '#'
        self.fields['cost_pp'].required = False
        self.fields['number_ppl'].required = False        
        self.fields['number_ppl'].widget = HiddenInput()
```

Comment: Yes, that can be done with JavaScript.

Comment: Would it be possible to point me in the direction of some examples or references?